# How to encode string from readline() in UTF-8

Tags: android, string, encoding, utf-8

I am looking for a working solution to encode a string in UTF-8.

I'm new in Android so be patient with me. ;)

I tried all solutions that I can find but nothing works!

Here is my code:

```java
public void Loader(String nameFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File(nameFile);
    FileInputStream f_is = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream b_is = new BufferedInputStream(f_is);
    BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(b_is));

    try {
        while ( (BufferTemp=data.readLine()) != null) {

            if (BufferTemp.contains("****")) {
                Titolo = data.readLine();
                Tempo = data.readLine();
                Persone = data.readLine();
                Piatto = data.readLine();
                Ingredienti = data.readLine();
                Altro = data.readLine();
                Descrizione = data.readLine();          
                EncodedBkg = data.readLine();
            }       
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

How can I encode `Descrizione` to a UTF-8 string??

I accept any solution, and all change to my code are welcome but I need to read the file line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's native `String` encoding in memory is UTF-16. `readLine()` returns a UTF-16 encoded `String`. It does not make sense to have a UTF-8 encoded `String`.

Is the real problem that the source file is UTF-8 encoded and you are having trouble reading non-ASCII characters from it? If so, use the charset parameter of the `InputStreamReader` constructor:

```
new InputStreamReader(b_is, "utf-8")
```

Or, do you really need to convert a UTF-16 encoded `String` to a UTF-8 encoded memory buffer?

```
ByteBuffer Descrizione_utf8 = Charset.forName("utf-8").encode(Descrizione);
```

Comment: I have a file .txt and when i try to put it in a textview characters like "è à ì ò ù" become "? ? ? ? ?" I tryed with `new InputStreamReader(b_is, "utf-8");` but doesn't work. Now i will try to encode the string with `ByteBuffer Descrizione_utf8 = Charset.forName("utf-8").encode(Descrizione);` Thanks

Comment: You don't need to encode a `String` just to display it in a `TextView`.  You are chasing the wrong problem. Did you verify that `readLine()` is returning the correct characters to begin with? If not, you need to start there. What is the file's actual encoding? Is it UTF-8 or Ansi?

Comment: It's a combination of various .txt merged in one file (binary mode), so i think is Ansi.

Comment: I verify if it's Ansi or UTF-8, and is Ansi, maybe something wrong when i saved file. Sorry for the inconvenience! It works with a new file!

Answer (score 0):

java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Descrizione", "UTF-8");

Comment: That would URLEncode the string in utf8 encoding, if it was read in a different format then it would garble. (e.g. UTF16)

Answer (score 0):

Your inputstream reader will default to the default encoding set on your device, (for example shift JIS or UTF16, depending on your locale settings )

Then to reset the encoding on your string call:

```
Descrizione = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(data.readLine());
```

Now that you have a string with a internal utf8 representation if you wish to format it in such a manner that you need to send it to a web server you can then call:

```
URLEncoder.encode (myString, "UTF-8");
```

which will escape a number of charecters in such a manner that they can be sent over a http GET or POST as paremeters.

Comment: `Descrizione = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(data.readLine());` which's the difference with `ByteBuffer Descrizione_utf8 = Charset.forName("utf-8").encode(Descrizione);`? In this case what's the return type of `Descrizione`?